# Error "Undefined index" if check box is not checked

Tags: php

When I check the checkbox there is no errors, but when I didn't check the checkbox it gives me errors.

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['btn']))
    {
        $remmber = $_REQUEST['active'];
    if($remmber == "on")
        {  
            echo "Checked";
        }
        else  {$remmber = "";}
    }
    ?>
    <html>
    <form name= "frm" action = "test.php" method = "post" >
    <p>Username
    <input  type = "text" name = "name" value = ""  />
    </p>

    <p>Password
    <input type = "text" name = "password" value = "" />
    </p>

    <p>
    <td colspan = "2"><input type = "checkbox" name = "active" value = "active" />Keep Me Loged In 
    </p>

    <p><input type = "submit" name = "btn" value = "Login" />

    </p>


    </form>
    </html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submit an HTML form with empty checkboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476426/submit-an-html-form-with-empty-checkboxes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For checkboxes if they are not checked then they are not posted. So check if it is present in the posted data then set `on`, else set `blank` to the variable. Try with -

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['btn']))
{
    $remmber = !empty($_REQUEST['active']) ? 'on' : '';
    if($remmber == "on")
    {  
        echo "Checked";
    }
    else 
        $remmber = "";
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Now its working but when i alredy used if else if it has on then its going to echo otherwise it is going to set $remember = "". than why it still giving errors. if($remmber == "on")
        {  
            echo "Checked";
        }
        else  {$remmber = "";}

Comment: You should explain _why_ you need to do it this way for checkboxes.

Comment: @AkshatDhiman See the other answer for why testing `== "on"` isn't working.

Comment: @Barmar i am just using this for login page , where i am using a checkbox to remember username and password.

Comment: @AkshatDhiman I'm not sure what that has to do with why you should test whether `$remmber == "active"` instead of `$remmber == "on"`

Answer (score 3):

`if($remmber == "on")` yet you're using and specifying a value `value = "active"`

- "on" is the default value for a checkbox if a value is not specified.

Therefore, you need to adjust it to read as

```
if($remmber == "active")
```

---

**Edit:** (an explanation)

The reason why you're getting an undefined index, is that once you hit the submit submit and do not tick the checkbox, it will produce that notice.

Modify your code to read as and check if the checkbox value is set.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['btn']))
{

    if(isset($_REQUEST['active'])){

    $remmber = $_REQUEST['active'];

    if($remmber == "active")
        {  
            echo "Checked";
        }
        else  {$remmber = "";}

    } // closing brace for if(isset($_REQUEST['active']))

}
```

---

Additional edit, to show the user that the checkbox isn't set:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['btn']))
{

    if(isset($_REQUEST['active'])){

    $remmber = $_REQUEST['active'];

    if($remmber == "active")
        {  
            echo "Checked";
        }
        else  {$remmber = "";}

    } // closing brace for if(isset($_REQUEST['active']))

    else{ echo "The checkbox was not ticked.";
    }

}
```

---

**Footnotes:**

- You should also use a conditional `!empty()` for your inputs.
- You're only checking if the submit and checkbox are set.

---

After noticing a comment you left in another answer:

> *@Barmar i am just using this for login page , where i am using a checkbox to remember username and password. –  Akshat Dhiman*

Please read the following Q&A on Stack:

- [Remember me Cookie best practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7214458/)

It also contains valuable information regarding passwords.

- I hope you are using modern-day hashing methods also, such as [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) as well as [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: The error is happening on the line `$remmber = $_REQUEST['active'];`.

Comment: @Barmar I know, but the OP is using `if($remmber == "on")` that value isn't specified they're using `value = "active"`. I'll be glad to adjust or delete my answer.

Comment: His question is about the "undefined index" warning. Your answer is important, but it's not directly related to his question.

Comment: @Barmar I will test it and will adjust my answer from my findings. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Fred-ii- actually, when the checkbox is unchecked, its not in post, so a simple `isset` or `empty` should suffice for checking, no need for that string value checking

Comment: @Barmar I've adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use simply `isset`

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['btn']))
{
    $remmber = isset($_REQUEST['active']) ? $_REQUEST['active'] : '';
    if($remmber == "on")
    {  
        echo "Checked";
    }
    else  {$remmber = "";}
}
```

Comment: Like I said in response to sgt BOSE's similar answer, you should explain _why_ this is necessary.