# How to have the log remember function without using cookies C# ASP .NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, cookies, authentication

I started learning to build a website, and 
I am building a log memory function (Remember me).

How to have the log remember function **without** using cookies ? 
I'm afraid of its security even when it's password-encrypted. 
I have found my password and login name from cookies!.

Facebook does not need cookies to save accounts, can we do like them?

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Vũ-Thành-Long  i think this is the best answer  so look at this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12335873/619131)

Comment: another answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/244907/619131)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server is single machine and you don't have to share data between instances, you can save user that are logged in in a dictionary, and save user by userid or IP.