# Get unique ID for image upload

Tags: php

What I want is upload an image, get unique ID and save this in server. I have two methods to get ID and I want to know if this is the right path for real application.

method 1

> round(microtime(true));

method 2

> md5(uniqid(rand(), true));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
Use cryptographic-ally unique id - uuidV4 to gaureente uniqueness

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31460273/3359432

You can use PHP inbuilt function `uniqid`. Available since PHP 4

Quoting from PHP official site

```
<?php
/* A uniqid, like: 4b3403665fea6 */
printf("uniqid(): %s\r\n", uniqid());

/* We can also prefix the uniqid, this the same as 
 * doing:
 *
 * $uniqid = $prefix . uniqid();
 * $uniqid = uniqid($prefix);
 */
printf("uniqid('php_'): %s\r\n", uniqid('php_'));

/* We can also activate the more_entropy parameter, which is 
 * required on some systems, like Cygwin. This makes uniqid()
 * produce a value like: 4b340550242239.64159797
 */
printf("uniqid('', true): %s\r\n", uniqid('', true));
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

You must also read the warning

> Warning This function does not guarantee uniqueness of return value.
>   Since most systems adjust system clock by NTP or like, system time is
>   changed constantly. Therefore, it is possible that this function does
>   not return unique ID for the process/thread. Use more_entropy to
>   increase likelihood of uniqueness.

Comment: Yes I 'am aware of this that's why I seek advice if my methods gonna work 100% uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Sure
You Can Use Md5 with current date and time

Comment: just a follow up question does it mean I won't get duplicate names? how about a scenario two users try to upload in the same machine and date/time.

Comment: you use with image name