# Access Token in PHP?

Tags: php

Hope You all are Fine .
im working in project using php + some mobile app , and we need users to login in from mobile app to site , so we need to generate access token , how can i generate it ? and if you know any another way tell me please .

Comment: I think your question is slightly similar to this one, hope it helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830839/generating-cryptographically-secure-tokens

Comment: i dont understand the old answer ....