# Generate save activation key as product key

Tags: php, security, random

I am trying to create a function which creates a random String. This String should consist of letters (only caps) and numbers. It will be used to activate a product. So the user has to type it into a text field.
So far I found the following function:

```
function random_str($length, $keyspace =  '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'){

  $pieces = [];
  $max = mb_strlen($keyspace, '8bit') - 1;
  for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
      $pieces []= $keyspace[random_int(0, $max)];
  }
  return implode('', $pieces);
}
```

I do not have that much experience with random functions. So is there anything to improve or would you suggest a different function?

Comment: use PHP function `uniqid();`, pro tip: also add a random number of around 8 digits to the end http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php then to apply to your exact requirements, encode as you wish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate a cryptographically secure random string (which I would recommend for an activation key), I would rather use *openssl_random_pseudo_bytes*

You can find the doc [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) and some useful informations in [that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830839/generating-cryptographically-secure-tokens) (for example, how to get a random string with 0-9A-Z characters rather than just 0-9A-F).

As of PHP7.0 you could also use [random_bytes](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php), which is also cryptographically secure.

Answer (score 0):

readable - [base64_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)([random_bytes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes)($lenght ) ); shorter

readable longer - [bin2hex](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex)(random_bytes($lenght ) );

To make with wanted length use [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr)

Answer (score -1):

Use **rand** function instead of **'random_int'**

```
function random_str($length, $keyspace =  
 '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'){

 $pieces = [];
 $max = mb_strlen($keyspace, '8bit') - 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
  $pieces []= $keyspace[rand(0, $max)];
 }
 return implode('', $pieces);
}

 echo random_str('50');

// Output //

P7V55MYPQJGRNQ8W0VW7TRKBDK2B7NXWUT20F0P6J5Y7W63X20
```