# How do I prevent other users from hijacking the HTTP request payload as other users?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-middleware

## I have

a Laravel app with the route

```
Route::put('/api/{deviceMac}/access/update','DeviceController@update');
```

## Rule

If user A have deviceMac `000000000000`, should only be making a PUT to

```
http://www.app.com/api/000000000000/access/update
{deviceMac:000000000000, access: true}
```

If user B have deviceMac `111111111111`, should only be making a PUT to

```
http://www.app.com/api/111111111111/access/update
{deviceMac:111111111111, access: true}
```

> User A should not be able hijacking the route update of other users

## Hijacking

User A should have access to `000000000000` only.

Right now, **User A** can tweak the HTTP request and make a PUT as **User B**

```
http://www.app.com/api/111111111111/access/update
{deviceMac:111111111111, access: false}
```

## Questions

How do I prevent other users from hijacking the request payload as other users?

Should I adjust my middleware to take care of this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a token based system.

Have some sort of sign in or even something as simple as when a user opens your app you send a request to your server with the MAC address of the current user and generate a token ([`bin2hex(random_bytes(30))`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830839/generating-cryptographically-secure-tokens), note this will generate a 60 character token which may or may not seem excessive) which is assigned to this MAC address.

Then, you can create a [custom middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#defining-middleware) that checks if the MAC address being sent has a token AND that the token matches the MAC address it was assigned to at startup.

On sign out don't forget to invalidate the token and if you don't have a sign out, keep tokens alive on a time basis (actually, this step is advisable even if you have an explicit sign out button).

Finally, I would highly recommend that you update to the latest version of Laravel as you seem to be falling quite behind. The current version is 5.7 compared to your 5.1.