# bin2hex() Cuts off Trailing Zeros

Tags: php, bin2hex

I have a form that inserts items into a MySQL database upon submission. I have decided to create 16 bit IDs for the items using the `random_bytes` method in PHP so that every time the form submits I already know the ID and don't have to re-query the database for it for it.

In order to insert the ID into a link in the page I have tried using the `bin2hex` method. This normally works correctly. However, when the ID has trailing zeros the method seems to cut them off (passing in the direct result of the `random_bytes` method). In other pages where I use the function on the same ID retrieved from the database it does not do this and works correctly.

In other words, if the ID ends in 000, it is shown correctly in the hexadecimal representation when `bin2hex` is called on the database retrieved binary representation. However, the zeros are missing in the hexadecimal representation when the function is called on the direct output of the `random_bytes` function.

Here is the initial code:

```
$uuid = random_bytes(16);
$uuidHex = bin2hex($uuid);
```

Later in the same script:

```
$GLOBALS["ID"]  = '0x' . $uuidHex;
```

Script inside link `href` attribute:

```
<?php echo $ID; ?>
```

Here is an example ID where the problem would occur:

`0xa87ea4fc142fcdeasjf90j3771eda500`

Comment: What is a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do we ever know that `bin2hex` is cutting of trailing zeros?

```php
$uuid = random_bytes(16);
```

This is unreadable, this will give you **cryptographically strong** random bytes. We convert it to hexadecimal.

```php
$uuidHex = bin2hex($uuid);
```

Now this will give you a random string of **32 bits** not 16. But why? Because, in hex, a byte is always expressed as 2 characters. Divide 32 by 2. Also, you are adding "'0x'" to in the string which will make it 18 bit. To get a resultant of 16 bits, Do this

```php
$uuid = random_bytes(7);
$uuidHex = bin2hex($uuid);
$GLOBALS["ID"]  = '0x' . $uuidHex; // 16 bit string
```

Because with `random_bytes(7)` we are getting 7 times 2 of string length which is 14 and then we append "0x" which makes is `14 + 2` `=` a `16` bit string

Comment: The $uuid is added directly into the database row. The $uuidHex is for another page to catch the ID from the URL and search for it. The '0x' is added so that the database reads it is binary in the other page's query.

Comment: @user7412419 don't do that. Push `bin2hex($uuid); ` to the database see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830839/generating-cryptographically-secure-tokens/18841555

Comment: I think that might have been the issue. I changed it to push the HEX string instead of the raw binary and the issue has seemed to stop occurring.